# Ansible: how to set hostname before DNS assigned

Tags: ansible

Does anyone have a better solution for configuring instances with a hostname before that hostname can be assigned to the server?

Let's say we're using AWS and instantiate instance *ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com*. When it's configured, we'll eventually assign it a CNAME in DNS of *new-instance.example.com* to replace an existing instance already in production.

*new-instance.example.com* already exists and is in production, so we can't reassign the CNAME to *ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com* until the machine is configured properly and we're ready to switch over. We want internal configuration files and the hostname on the instance to be *new-instance.example.com* now, however, in preparation for the DNS change. So we can't use the **inventory_hostname** variable because it will be *ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com*. I also have normal production servers that don't need to use a new hostname, so I'd like to be able to use the existing **inventory_hostname** with them.

My best idea so far has been to assign a variable in the inventory file:

```
[production]
ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com new_hostname=new-instance.example.com
```

In the playbook, I can test for the existence of **new_hostname**. If **new_hostname** exists, it's used and if it doesn't, **inventory_hostname** is used. This will cause a fatal error unless **error_on_undefined_vars** is set to *false* and I'd prefer not to set this for the benefit it provides of preventing typos.  An example of failure below.

Test Playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: "Debug hostname"
      debug: msg="inventory_hostname={{ inventory_hostname }}, hostvars[inventory_hostname]['inventory_hostname']={{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['inventory_hostname'] }}, ansible_hostname={{ ansible_hostname }}, new_hostname={{ new_hostname }}"
      ignore_errors: yes
```

Results:

```
TASK: [Debug hostname] ********************************************************
fatal: [ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com] => One or more undefined variables: 'new_hostname' is undefined
```

Setting **new_hostname** for every single server would work, but I don't want to set it for every one, just the ones that need the new hostname. It also breaks hostname grouping like:

*ec2-1-2-3-[4:5].compute-1.amazonaws.com*

If **new_hostname** exists, this works:

```
- name: "set hostname fact"
  set_fact: testvar1={{ new_hostname }} || {{ inventory_hostname }}

- name: "show hostname fact"
  debug: msg="testvar1={{ testvar1 }}"
```

Results:

```
TASK: [set hostname fact] *****************************************************
ok: [ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com]

TASK: [show hostname fact] ****************************************************
ok: [ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com] => {"msg": "testvar1=new-instance.example.com"}
```

If **error_on_undefined_vars** is set to the default of *true*, however, and **new_hostname** is not set, it fails.

Best practices on this strategy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Being very shy on this because I am also new to ansible and if I understand your problem, one way is to use `when: something is defined` on the task.

Example:

```
  tasks:
    - name: "Debug hostname"
      debug: msg="inventory_hostname={{ inventory_hostname }}, hostvars[inventory_hostname]['inventory_hostname']={{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['inventory_hostname'] }}, ansible_hostname={{ ansible_hostname }}, new_hostname={{ new_hostname }}"
      when: new_hostname is defined
```

Now that's one approach. Another would be to make a role for that and only play that role (the spinning up procedure) separately to a target machine from an added entry in the inventory maybe. Take a look at the [best practices](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html) if you like as well for some extra reading.

Comment: Don't think this approach works with `when` because it expects a boolean, not a string.

Comment: @Rico oups sorry forgot the defined. Cope paste rename mistakes. See corrected answer

Comment: @JimmyKane here's the gist with the working solution:
https://gist.github.com/davestern/8976317

Comment: @DaveStern Great and glad that I helped. Great tool Ansible.

Answer (score 4):

When standing up [cloud-init](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit) to set the hostname.  (I use Chef but that isn't relevant to the solution here).  This gets around the problem of setting the hostname in your automation framework as it's already set by the time the node boots.

Part of my cloud config sets the `fqdn` and `manage_etc_hosts` options like so:

```
fqdn: new-instance.example.com
manage_etc_hosts: true
```

There are plenty of example configuration fragments in the [doc/examples directory](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~cloud-init-dev/cloud-init/trunk/files/head:/doc/examples/) and it's easy to play around and find a setup that you like.

Answer (score 3):

One approach with `when` is the following if your DNS names have a pattern, given that you always define the `new_hostname` variable:

```
- include: tasks/sometasks.yml
  when: "'new' in new_hostname"
```

Then you can define the `new_hostname` variable in your inventory like you mentioned:

```
[production]
ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com new_hostname=new-instance.example.com
ec2-5-6-7-8.compute-1.amazonaws.com new_hostname=nada
```

The key here is always defining your variable and look for patterns that match or don't match. Your inventory and command line variable should override your playbook variable.

To apply it more to your case:

```
tasks:
  - name: "set hostname fact"
    set_fact: testvar1={{ new_hostname }}
    when: "'new' in new_hostname"

  - name: "set hostname fact"
    set_fact: testvar1={{ inventory_hostname }}
    when: "'nada' in new_hostname"
```

Something to keep in mind is to not define the `new_hostname` variable in your playbook otherwise it your inventory variable will get overridden.

Also, you don't want to pass it through the command line which will override the one defined in the inventory file too (for all your servers):

```
ansible-playbook -i <your-inventory> -e "new_hostname=new-instance.example.com" yourplaybook.xml
```

This is according to the Ansible variable precedence:

> - -e variables always win
> - then comes "most everything else"
> - then comes variables defined in inventory
> - then "role defaults", which are the most "defaulty" and lose in priority to everything.

Comment: This is great @Rico. I believe I can accomplish this without all the extra logic by just defining the `new_hostname=ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com` instead of `nada` for instances where I want to use the inventory_hostname.

The benefit I'd like to achieve, however, is to be able to use hostname grouping for those types of servers and not have to set the `new_hostname` for instance groups that don't require it.

Answer (score 0):

```
[production]]

ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com new_hostname=new-instance.example.com
```

I think it is ok to set the host name this way, but Ansible may require a separate host

```
  tasks:

     - name: change name

       raw: "echo {{new_hostname|quote}} > /etc/hostname"

     - name:

       shell: hostname {{new_hostname|quote}}
```